# c++ - reinterpret_cast to type from buffer

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there is a good way to solve this problem without making alot of copies.

Lets say for instance that I have a byte-buffer which i save alot of stuff to. I will correctly save 4 bytes for a integer in there and floats etc.

Now if my integer is saved at location 0x0001 in the buffer, is there a way i could create a int* and point it to that location?

I have tried:

```
int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&data.dataPtr);
```

and dataPtr is a `const char*` which ofc holds the address to my integer within the buffer.

After my cast ptr holds the address of dataPtr and when I dereference ptr, it prints the address of dataPtr. Should I cast it again with static_cast or reinterpret_cast to get the integer?

Is this even possible without running into undefined behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee that this works, but you can make it work on certain compilers and systems.

First of all, you probably want to cast `data.dataPtr` and not `&data.dataPtr`. You want to point to the buffer pointed to by `data.dataPtr`, correct? Not to the pointer variable itself. Second, if `dataPtr` is `const`, then you should make `ptr` const too, to ensure some safety. So we have:

```
const int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<const int*>(data.dataPtr);
```

This still has some problems.

`data.dataPtr` may not store an address aligned for `int`, in which case it may not work. Some systems support misaligned pointers, some don't. On those that do, it is often slow.

`data.dataPtr` may not store enough data to make up an `int`.

If it works so far, the exact value of the `int` will be different depending on the endianness of the system.

Sometimes it is acceptable to make use of system or compiler specific behavior, but only if you know exactly what you are doing and why it will work.

To do this in a standard-complaint way, you will have to grab the bytes one by one and use bit shifting to compose them into an `int`.

You should also be aware of pointer aliasing.

Comment: Oh man cheers, I was confusing myself alot there, you are the best.